# Return HTTP code for GAE ProtoRPC

Tags: python, google-app-engine, protorpc

How do I control the HTTP Status Code in the `protoRPC` response?

Let's say I have the following service:

```
class ApiService(remote.Service):

    @remote.method(ApiRequestContextCreate, ApiResponseContextCreate)
    def context_create(self, request):
        cid = helpers.create_context(request.name)
        return ApiResponseContextCreate(cid=cid)
```

Looks to me that the protoRPC API is lacking semantics: either the request can be fulfilled and returns a `200` or an exception is raised yielding to a `404`. Of course of could craft an error response in the RPC method but that seems kludgy.

Update:  I have found I can raise `ApplicationError` too for a `400`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTP status code is not part of the specification for ProtoRPC because ProtoRPC is meant to support protocols besides HTTP.  It therefore cannot have specific-to-HTTP return codes.  Instead, errors are returns by raising ApplicationError, using the error_name field to specify application specific error conditions.